# recursive n-th child dict.get() - efficiency?

Tags: python

I need to get some values out of some big nested dictionaries. Out of laziness I decided to write a function that recursively calls itself until the last child is found, or the leaf is empty.

Since there are dictionaries popped out and with every new call there's a new dictionary built, I wonder how efficient this is.

Any suggestions?

```
def recursive_dict_get(item, string, default=False):
    if not isinstance(item, dict):
        return default

    print "called with ", item, "and string", string
    if "." in string:
        attrs = string.split(".")
        parent = attrs.pop(0)
        rest = ".".join(attrs)
        result = item.get(parent, None)
        if result is None:
            return default
        else:
            return recursive_dict_get(item.get(parent, default), rest, default)
    else:
        return item.get(string, default)
```

## ---

```
foo = {
            "1": {
                "2": {
                    "3": {
                        "4":{
                            "5": {
                                "6": {
                                    "7": "juice"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

print recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7", False)
print "*" * 3       
print recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6", False)
print "*" * 3
print recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.3", False)
```

Comment: I'm confused - are you asking if there's a better way to do this or how to test the efficiency?

Comment: You aren't building any new dictionaries with your code.

Comment: a quick-n-dirty way: `print reduce(dict.get, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7".split('.'), nested_dict)`. See [more general version that also allows to change values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One suggestion I have is to give `split()` a second argument. You can do something simpler like:

```
parent, rest = string.split(".", 1)
```

Other than that, I see no immediate issues with the code.

You can also do this without recursion:

```
def recursive_dict_get(item, string, default=False):
    for s in string.split('.'):
        if (isinstance(item, dict) and s in item):
            item = item[s]
        else:
            return default
    return item
```

Comment: I prefer iterative over recursive.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your implementation is fairly inefficient, even though it isn't building any new dictionaries, bur rather returns potentially a lot of existing ones. Regardless, you could adapt the accepted answer to [*Access python nested dictionary items via a list of keys*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747/355230) to **reduce** your access function to one line of code. This is similar to what J.F. Sebastian (@jfs) alluded to in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339073/recursive-n-th-child-dict-get-efficiency#comment26920139_18339073). My take on it would be something like this:

```
def nonrecursive_dict_get(item, key_string, default=False):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k, default), key_string.split('.'), item)

print "*" * 3, 'using nonrecursive_dict_get()'
print nonrecursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7")
print "*" * 3
print nonrecursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6")
print "*" * 3
print nonrecursive_dict_get(foo, "1.3")
```

**Update:**

Whenever efficiency is a concern, often the best thing to do is run a benchmark of the various approaches. Here's one I've used a number of times:

```
global_setup = """
    foo = {
            "1": {
                "2": {
                    "3": {
                        "4": {
                            "5": {
                                "6": {
                                    "7": "juice"
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
          }
"""

testcases = {
"jay":
    { 'setup' : """
        def recursive_dict_get(item, string, default=False):
            if not isinstance(item, dict):
                return default
            if "." in string:
                attrs = string.split(".")
                parent = attrs.pop(0)
                rest = ".".join(attrs)
                result = item.get(parent, None)
                if result is None:
                    return default
                else:
                    return recursive_dict_get(item.get(parent, default), rest, default)
            else:
                return item.get(string, default)
                """,
      'code' : """
        recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7", False)
        recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6", False)
        recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.3", False)
        """,
    },

"martineau":
    { 'setup' : """
        def nonrecursive_dict_get(nested_dict, key_string, default=False):
            return reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k, default), key_string.split('.'), nested_dict)
            """,
      'code' : """
        nonrecursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7", False)
        nonrecursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6", False)
        nonrecursive_dict_get(foo, "1.3", False)
        """,
    },

"J.F. Sebastian":
    { 'setup' : """
        # modified to support 'default' keyword argument
        def quick_n_dirty(nested_dict, key_string, default=False):
            reduced = reduce(dict.get, key_string.split('.'), nested_dict)
            return default if reduced is None else reduced
            """,
      'code' : """
        quick_n_dirty(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7", False)
        quick_n_dirty(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6", False)
        quick_n_dirty(foo, "1.3", False)
        """,
    },

"arshajii":
    { 'setup' : """
        def recursive_dict_get(item, string, default=False):
            for s in string.split('.'):
                if (isinstance(item, dict) and s in item):
                    item = item[s]
                else:
                    return default
            return item
            """,
      'code' : """
        recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7", False)
        recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6", False)
        recursive_dict_get(foo, "1.3", False)
        """,
    },

"Brionius":
    { 'setup' : """
        def getVal(d, keys, default):
            keys = keys.split(".")
            for key in keys:
                try:
                    d = d[key]
                except KeyError:
                    return default
            return d
            """,
      'code' : """
        getVal(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6.7", False)
        getVal(foo, "1.2.3.4.5.6", False)
        getVal(foo, "1.3", False)
        """,
    },
}

import sys
from textwrap import dedent
import timeit
N = 100000
R = 3

# remove leading whitespace from all code fragments
global_setup = dedent(global_setup)
for testcase in testcases.itervalues():
    for label, fragment in testcase.iteritems():
        testcase[label] = dedent(fragment)

timings = [(name,
            min(timeit.repeat(testcases[name]['code'],
                              setup=global_setup + testcases[name]['setup'],
                              repeat=R, number=N)),
           ) for name in testcases]

longest_name = max(len(t[0]) for t in timings)

print('fastest to slowest timings:\n'
      '  ({:,d} calls, best of {:d} repetitions)\n'.format(N, R))

ranked = sorted(timings, key=lambda t: t[1])  # sort by speed (fastest first)
for timing in ranked:
    print("{:>{width}} : {:.6f} secs ({rel:>8.6f}x)".format(
          timing[0], timing[1], rel=timing[1]/ranked[0][1], width=longest_name))
```

Output:

```
fastest to slowest timings:
  (100,000 calls, best of 3 repetitions)

J.F. Sebastian : 1.287209 secs (1.000000x)
      Brionius : 1.420099 secs (1.103239x)
      arshajii : 1.431521 secs (1.112112x)
     martineau : 2.031539 secs (1.578251x)
           jay : 7.817713 secs (6.073384x)
```

As you can see, J.F. Sebastian's suggestion is the fastest, even with the modification I put in to make it the same as the others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
def getVal(d, keys, default):
    keys = keys.split(".")  # You can avoid this first step if you're willing to use a list like ["1", "2", "3"...] as an input instead of a string like "1.2.3..."
    for key in keys:
        try:
            d = d[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
    return d
```

I can profile it if you want - let me know.  Keep in mind there's no point in optimizing unless you've encountered or have reason to believe you will encounter a bottleneck.

Comment: This would also need the type check: `if not isinstance(d, dict): return default` (because d[key] on a non-dict will not necessarily raise KeyError).

Comment: Could be, if the keys and values of the dict tree aren't always strings.  I'll leave that to the OP to add in, if their sample input is not representative.

Comment: +1 For performance based on benchmark results and a certain amount of elegance.