# How can I change the value of a node in a python dictionary by following a list of keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a bit of a complex question that I can't seem to get to the bottom of. I have a list of keys corresponding to a position in a Python dictionary. I would like to be able to dynamically change the value at the position (found by the keys in the list).

For example:

```
listOfKeys = ['car', 'ford', 'mustang']
```

I also have a dictionary:

```
DictOfVehiclePrices = {'car':
                          {'ford':
                              {'mustang': 'expensive',
                               'other': 'cheap'},
                           'toyota':
                              {'big': 'moderate',
                               'small': 'cheap'}
                          },
                       'truck':
                          {'big': 'expensive',
                           'small': 'moderate'}
                      }
```

Via my list, how could I dynamically change the value of `DictOfVehiclePrices['car']['ford']['mustang']`?

In my actual problem, I need to follow the list of keys through the dictionary and change the value at the end position. How can this be done dynamically (with loops, etc.)?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem):

```
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> lis = ['car', 'ford', 'mustang']
```

Update value:

```
>>> reduce(getitem, lis[:-1], DictOfVehiclePrices)[lis[-1]] = 'cheap'
```

Fetch value:

```
>>> reduce(getitem, lis, DictOfVehiclePrices)
'cheap'
```

---

Note that in Python 3 `reduce` has been moved to [functools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) module.

Comment: This will allow you to retrieve the value, but the questioner wants to be able to modify it.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing the obvious with this question, but what would "getitem" be? I can't quite figure it out...

Comment: @user2590203 `from operator import getitem`

Comment: Ok sorry! I missed that... :/

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach would be:

```
DictOfVehiclePrices[listOfKeys[0]][listOfKeys[1]][listOfKeys[2]] = 'new value'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], listOfKeys, dictOfVehiclePrices)
```

**Output**

```
expensive
```

In order to change the values,

```
result = dictOfVehiclePrices
for key in listOfKeys[:-1]:
    result = result[key]

result[listOfKeys[-1]] = "cheap"
print dictOfVehiclePrices
```

**Output**

```
{'car': {'toyota': {'small': 'cheap', 'big': 'moderate'},
 'ford': {'mustang': 'cheap', 'other': 'cheap'}},
 'truck': {'small': 'moderate', 'big': 'expensive'}}
```

Comment: This will allow you to retrieve the value, but the questioner wants to be able to modify it.

Comment: It won't allow to change the value, It's simply a lookup.

Comment: Nice, but you'd probably want to slice the list so you get the first ones and use `setitem` or something on the final value.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918901/1982962) by @Joel Cornett.

based on **Joel** method you can use it like this:

```
def set_value(dict_nested, address_list):
    cur = dict_nested
    for path_item in address_list[:-2]:
        try:
            cur = cur[path_item]
        except KeyError:
            cur = cur[path_item] = {}
    cur[address_list[-2]] = address_list[-1]

DictOfVehiclePrices = {'car':
                      {'ford':
                          {'mustang': 'expensive',
                           'other': 'cheap'},
                       'toyota':
                          {'big': 'moderate',
                           'small': 'cheap'}
                      },
                   'truck':
                      {'big': 'expensive',
                       'small': 'moderate'}
                  }

set_value(DictOfVehiclePrices,['car', 'ford', 'mustang', 'a'])

print DictOfVehiclePrices
```

- **STDOUT:**

> {'car': {'toyota': {'small': 'cheap', 'big': 'moderate'}, 'ford':
>   {'mustang': 'a', 'other': 'cheap'}}, 'truck': {'small': 'moderate',
>   'big': 'expensive'}}

Answer (score -1):

```
def update_dict(parent, data, value):
    '''
    To update the value in the data if the data
    is a nested dictionary
    :param parent: list of parents
    :param data: data dict in which value to be updated
    :param value: Value to be updated in data dict
    :return:
    '''
    if parent:
        if isinstance(data[parent[0]], dict):
            update_dict(parent[1:], data[parent[0]], value)
        else:
            data[parent[0]] = value


parent = ["test", "address", "area", "street", "locality", "country"]
data = {
    "first_name": "ttcLoReSaa",
    "test": {
        "address": {
            "area": {
                "street": {
                    "locality": {
                        "country": "india"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
update_dict(parent, data, "IN")
```

Here is a recursive function to update a nested dict based on a list of keys:

1.Trigger the update dict function with the required params

2.The function will iterate the list of keys, and retrieves the value from the dict.

3.If the retrieved value is dict, it pops the key from the list and also it updates the dict with the value of the key.

4.Sends the updated dict and list of keys to the same function recursively.

5.When the list gets empty, it means that we have reached the desired the key, where we need to apply our replacement. So if the list is empty, the funtion replaces the dict[key] with the value