# Any Functional Programming method of traversing a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to find a better way to implement this:

```
d = {"a": {"b": {"c": 4}}} 
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
for x in l:
    d = d[x]
print (d) # 4
```

I am learning functional programming so I am just trying random example that come to my head :)

Comment: Your are indirectly calling d = d["c"] which is 4...

Comment: Hi Nilesh, Thanks for replying, but i guess I failed to explain my question correctly to you. Please Martijn Answer below. Anyways thanks for the help :) Cheers!

Comment: related: [Python: Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
reduce(dict.__getitem__, l, d)
```

or better still, using [`operator.getitem()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem):

```
from operator import getitem

reduce(getitem, l, d)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {"a": {"b": {"c": 4}}} 
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> reduce(getitem, l, d)
4
```

Python 3 moved the `reduce()` function out of the built-ins and into [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Comment: Why not simply `dict.get`?

Comment: @thg435: Both work, both lead to an error if a key is missing, but the `dict.__getitem__` error would be clearer, I'd say (`KeyError` vs. `AttributeError`).

Comment: From a style point of view, is it better to use `dict.__getitem__` or `lambda d, k: d[k]` here?

Comment: @Eric: There is a 3rd option: `dict.get`. I prefer `dict.__getitem__` here; the error message is clearer when there is a key missing (`dict.get` will get you a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`). The `lambda` is a lot more verbose and slower.

Comment: [`operator.getitem`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) was the function I was looking for, which has the advantage of working on nested lists as well

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're confusing it with `itemgetter`, which is exactly the mistake I would have made 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: @Eric: bah, so I did. `operator.getitem()` is a great idea, works beautifully, and will get a place in this answer!

Comment: @Eric: [as far as I remember](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11919150/4279), `operator.getitem()` may produce different exceptions from `dict.__getitem__` -- whether it is important depends on the application.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: not sure that it does; it raises `KeyError` just fine for me. Do you have any specifics? `operator.getitem` is just the C `PyObject_GetItem` function, which is what all C code uses to access keys on dictionaries.

Comment: Consider what happens if you give a list to operator.getitem and dict.__getitem__

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `{}.__getitem__('foo')` and `operator.getitem({}, 'foo')` both raise a `KeyError`. Are you talking about the *attribute error* when the object doesn't have a `__getitem__` method? In that case the exceptions differ, yes; `AttributeError` vs. `TypeError`. But that hardly matters here, does it?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: that's because `operator.getitem(obj, key)` follows the ``obj[key]` notation (the same C function is used when the bytecode for indexing is executed).

Comment: You misunderstood: consider the difference between `reduce(dict.__getitem__, l, d)` and `reduce(operator.getitem, l, d)` -- if `d` has  a list instead of a dict at some level then `dict.__getitem__` raises `TypeError` while `operator.getitem` might succeed accidentally or raise `IndexError` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: right, passing in the wrong type for the first argument of `dict.__getitem__` you mean. I don't think it matters here; you'll never account for all the possible mistakes the caller of a function could make, it is their responsibility to pass in valid objects. :-)

Comment: I prefer solutions that detect errors earlier such as `dict.__getitem__` here.

Comment: It's a very good tips. I made a function for this https://gist.github.com/av1m/3517b2eff6615c7c12a6cb31aa86fe5d